# "Error inflating class fragment" with google map on xamarin

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, xamarin

I have xamarin for an android app. I would like an ActionBar with tabs and a google map on one tab.

It works but only one time when i click on the map tab.

I explain, the app launched, im on the event tab, i click on map tab, the map works correctly but when i go back to event tab and again map tab, it crash.

**Main:**

```
ActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled (true);
ActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled (true);
ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled (true);
ActionBar.SetTitle (Resource.String.app_name);
ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

var fragMap = new MapPageFragment();
ActionBar.Tab tab2 = ActionBar.NewTab();
tab2 = ActionBar.NewTab();
tab2.SetText("Map");
tab2.TabSelected += delegate(object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
     {
         e.FragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, fragMap);
};
ActionBar.AddTab(tab2);
```

**MapPageFragment:**

```
namespace OnmappTest
{
    public class MapPageFragment : Android.App.Fragment
    {
         public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapPage, container, false);
```

**The error**

> binary xml file line #1: error inflating class fragment" on "view =
>   inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapPage, container, false);

**MapPage**

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="OnmappTest.OnmappTest">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 requires OpenGL ES v2 -->
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<!-- We need to be able to download map tiles and access Google Play Services-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Allow the application to access Google web-based services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 needs this permission so that it may check the connection state as it must download data -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application android:label="OnmappTest" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <!-- Put your Google Maps V2 API Key here. -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="value" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

I tried `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`, `FragmentActivity` instead of Fragment but nothing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Please add this to OnPause method:

```
 protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        if (_mapFragment != null)
        {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = FragmentManager;
            fragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Remove(_mapFragment).Commit();
        }
    }
```

This solved my problem, hope that will solve yours.